# Как инициализировать не первое поле юниона?

Tags: c++, union

Как инициализировать не первое поле юниона?

```
#include <iostream>

union Union { 
    char a;
    int b; 
};

int main() {
    Union u = ???;
    std::cout << u.b << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

union Union
{ 
    char a;
    int b; 
};

int main()
{
    Union u{.b{42}};
    std::cout << u.b << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q9zzeb

Comment: только стандарт нужно не менее 20го... а так все ок.

Comment: А можно ведь просто:   `Union u{ 42 };`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Нет, не можно, выражение `Union u{ 42 };` инициализирует поле `a`.

Comment: @user7860670, это же объединение !..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan И что с того? Выражение `Union u{ 42 };` инициализирует поле `a`.

Comment: Нет, инициализируется поле, захваченное объединением: обе члена будут инициализированы